# Monitor server / website load of bandwith

Tags: ubuntu, monitoring, network-monitoring

I've been doing a lot of searching around for a tool to monitor a website's "bandwidth" usage, and I'm not talking about how many MB/data is being loaded but the servers actual output speed, to clarify what I mean I'll use an' example,

> My server has a Internet connection at 100/MBs, I want to be able to
>   monitor how much of that 100/MBs is being used, and have it being
>   logged, (As a background process).

I've tried different kind of tools such as Zabbix, Nagios and ntopng(ntop), all useful tools but none of them seem cable of logging the actual server speed / usage of the speed. Currently I still have Ntop(ng) installed but I am unable to get it to do what I want it to. (it is vital that the data is logged 24/7)

The reason for this is that due to me hosting files that people can download I am with the low internet connection sometimes hitting that cap, and I want to be able to monitor when / how offen I hit that cap.

My server is a Ubuntu 12.04 running with Apache 2.2, I don't know whether it's needed but in case: My domains are setup with Virtual hosts for each domain.

I appreciate any help and hints I can get.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what's wrong with for example Zabbix default network graphs + triggers?

Comment: What I was able to get Zabbix to do was not what I needed, it seems like it didn't log / show me the actual server(network) speed being used. It is highly possible that I haven't been able to configure it correctly. I'm not looking for a "trigger" since I don't just want to be notified when it hits the cap, but I want to be able to log the entire server's "network" speed(as explained in the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to monitor full network bandwidth by measuring web server output as noted in its logs - this would not be sufficient as that not include any TCP/IP protocol overheads or other traffic (any SSH, FTP, database, or other traffic that the server might take part in).

What you need to be watching is *interface statistics*. Any server monitoring tool such as Zabbix and Nagios will have a function for that, for instance with collectd you would use either the interfaces module (https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin:Interface) to monitor all traffic on a given interface or the iptables module (https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin:IPTables) to monitor traffic that matches certain filtering rules (so you can analyse the bandwidth used in more detail).

Comment: I'm not trying to fetch the data from the log, but I want the data I find / get to be logged, atleast that's how I understood your reply? None the less I will try out the two links you tried and come back.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a script (my favorite would be python with "re" module) to parse Apache access log

For an example:

127.0.0.1 - frank [10/Oct/2000:13:55:36 -0700] "GET /apache_pb.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 2326

The last element is the bytes transferred to the client. You need to keep adding this number and print or log at a regular frequency to produce the total bytes transferred to the client from the last run till that moment.

For more information on Apache access log, see here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html

```
#!/bin/env python
import time, sys, re

regex = re.compile(r'\s+([0-9]+)$')


def fetch_bytes(file, bytes):
        for line in file:
                match = regex.search(line)
                if match:
                        bytes = int(match.group(1))
                        yield bytes


def main():
        Access_File = "apache_access_log"
        try:
                with open(Access_File) as file:
                        gen = None
                        while True:
                                for i in range(1001):
                                        gen = fetch_bytes(file, bytes)
                                #bytes += sum(gen)
                                #prints how much KB has been transferred in the time duration
                                print "%s\t%dKB" % (time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"), (sum(gen)/1024))
                                time.sleep(120)

        except IOError:
                print "Could not locate the apache log file"
                sys.exit(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Comment: That would only monitor web server input+output, not any other sort of traffic (SSH, database calls if the web server accesses a database on another host, FTP connections, and so forth). Also it won't take into account TCP/IP overheads.